# using sudo inside virtual environment

Tags: command-line, server, sudo

If you have a virtual environment activated and used "sudo", does the command execute within the boundaries of the virtual environment or outside it ?

Comment: What kind of "virtual environment" ?

Comment: @sorenA python virtual environment